# Automated process for terminal

Tags: java, selenium, appium

If I want to do an automated process of opening a terminal window then give a command to Gradle to build app.  Is it possible ? I’m using Java.(Mac)

Something like - open terminal > type cd to the directory > then  type ~/gradlw

Thank you all

Comment: Do you want an actual terminal box to open up, the 'terminal' app to be front-most, and actually show `cd someDir` and then `~/gradlew` printed there, or, do you... just want to run gradlew in the stated directory? Because the former is vastly more complicated than the latter.

Comment: Hey , I want to open new terminal window then navigate to the gradle project folder and then run command gradl build